# Tabulating GLM summaries for each predictor, for multiple GLM fits

Tags: r, glm, summary, tabulate

All, I am looking for an efficient way to do the following in R.

I have a list of R GLM objects `G` that all use the same model matrix `X`. Each GLM object just corresponds to a different response variable `Y1... Yp`.

I would like to create a summary list `S` such that `S[[i]]` is a data frame with the `p`^th row containing the `summary(G[[p]])$coefficients[i,]` for the `p` response variables in each row. Thus, the length of list `S`, `length(S)`, will correspond to the total number of columns in `X`. The number of rows of `S[[i]]`, `nrow(S[[i]])`, will equal the number of response variables.

Currently, I am running summaries for each object, and then extracting corresponding to each column in X. So I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to approach this.

Comment: This isn't bad but `broom::tidy()` might be a good starting point

Comment: `sapply(G, coef)` ?

Comment: @BenBolker, that's great and so simple!! Thank you! But I see it only gives back the coefficients. The standard error, test statistic and p-value summaries are missing.

Comment: OK. And the number of *columns* of `S[[i]]` is the number of columns of the summary ?

Comment: Now I'm wondering why `lapply(G, summary)` isn't the answer to your question ... ?